# There is a script which should authorize automatically, it works, but i want to take password from .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, expect

Bash script (name: script.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avz username@ip:/fileineed /home
```

Expect script

```
#!/bin/expect
spawn ./script
expect “password:”
answer “pass” #i want to take answer from a file which name is password.txt
expect “$”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[expect](/questions/tagged/expect) is an extension of the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) language

To read a file, you need to [`open`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm) the file, [`read`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/read.htm) from the opened channel and then [`close`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/close.htm) the channel.

`read` by default includes the trailing newline in the result. [`string trim`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) can strip it off but read has an option to do it.

```
set f [open password.txt r]
set password [read -nonewline $f]
close $f
send -- "$password\r"
```